# How to declare local property from composition API in Vue 3?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

In Vue 2 I would do this:

```
<script>
    export default {
      props: ['initialCounter'],
      data() {
        return { counter: this.initialCounter }
      }
    }
</script>
```

In Vue 3 I tried this:

```
<script setup>
   import { ref } from 'vue';
   defineProps({ 'initialCounter': Number })
   const counter = ref(props.initialCounter)
</script>
```

This obviously doesn't work because `props` is undefined.

How can I bind one-way properties to a local variable in Vue 3?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems the result of `defineProps` is not assigned as a variable. check [Vue3 official doc on defineProps](https://vuejs.org/api/sfc-script-setup.html). Not really sure what is the use case of `ref()` here but [toRef](https://vuejs.org/api/reactivity-utilities.html#toref) API can be used as well.

```js
import { ref } from 'vue';
const props = defineProps({ 'initialCounter': Number })
const counter = ref(props.initialCounter)
```

Answer (score 1):

Retrieving a read-only value and assigning it to another one is a bad practice if your component is not a form but for example styled input. You have an answer to your question, but I want you to point out that the better way to change props value is to emit `update:modalValue` of parent `v-model` passed to child component.

**And this is how you can use it:**

```js
<template>
    <div>
        <label>{{ label }}</label>
        <input v-bind="$attrs" :placeholder="label" :value="modelValue" @input="$emit('update:modelValue', $event.target.value)">
        <span v-for="item of errors">{{ item.value }}</span>
    </div>
</template>

<script setup>
defineProps({ label: String, modelValue: String, errors: Array })
defineEmits(['update:modelValue'])
</script>
```

`v-bind="$attrs"` point where passed attributes need to be assigned. Like `type="email"` attribute/property of a DOM element.

**And parent an email field:**

```js
<BaseInput type="email" v-model="formData.email" :label="$t('sign.email')" :errors="formErrors.email" @focusout="validate('email')"/>
```

In this approach, `formdata.email` in parent will be dynamically updated.

Comment: "Retrieving a read-only value and assigning it to another one is a bad practice" - it's certainly not if this is how it's supposed to work. That it's called "initial" suggests that it really is.

Comment: @EstusFlask Ok if he wants to pass it to edit from, it's ok. I had on my mind custom styled input. I edited answer.